# How to keep rarely-used Li-Ion batteries functional?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, low-battery

I have many gadgets around the house that I don't use often, recently I notice that a battery failed on an Mp3 player not used for a year. The battery now has a life of 1 minute from the original 5-7 hours.

What would be the maximum amount of time to leave a Li-Ion uncharched that would not make the batteries unusable.

What other considerations should I take if I use rarely a device to be able to still use the battery, should I leave it fully charged, etc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Optimum temperature: 15 degrees Celsius and even lower
- Optimum state-of-charge: 40 %
- Avoid temperatures above 30 degrees Celsius (both during usage and storage)

Note that after 300 to 500 charge/discharge cycles, the battery may never be able to charge at its full capacity.

Here is an useful table:

[image]
By Isidor Buchmann. [How to Prolong Lithium-based Batteries](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_store_batteries)

Sources: batteryuniversity.com: [How to Store Batteries](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_store_batteries) and [How to Prolong Lithium-based Batteries](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries)

Comment: batteryuniversity.com is not a reliable source.